# table does not created properly within a function

Tags: javascript, django, html-table

I have a table like this below,

```
<table>
    <div id="boards"></div>
</table>
```

And I have a function like this,

```
function drawBoard(item, index) {
    boards = document.getElementById("boards");
    boards.innerHTML = boards.innerHTML + "<tr><td><div id=\x22Board" + index + "\x22></div></td></tr>";
}
```

Also, with {{winners}} as an array with 3 entries

```
var winners = {{winners}};
winners.forEach(drawBoard);
```

However, the table thus generated have got only 1 row instead of 3. Looks like the td and tr are ignored somehow. Any idea?

Comment: You can't have `<div>` inside `<table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks barmar. It works after I changed it to use div table instead as follows:

```
<div class="rTable">
    <div id="boards"></div>
</div>

function drawBoard(item, index) {
    boards = document.getElementById("boards");
    boards.innerHTML = boards.innerHTML + "<div class=\x22rTableRow\x22>";
    boards.innerHTML = boards.innerHTML + "<div class=\x22rTableCell\x22><div id=\x22Board" + index + "\x22></div></div>";
    boards.innerHTML = boards.innerHTML + "<div class=\x22rTableCell\x22>" + index + "</div>";
    boards.innerHTML = boards.innerHTML + "</div>";
}

var winners = {{winners}};
winners.forEach(drawBoard);
```